# EasyMock Long null match in method parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I want to match a method which has 3 paramters:
A String, A Long and A customObject

The test should match the String **exactly**, ensure that the Long is **null** and ensure that the custom object passed is of the correct **type**.

Something like:

```
    EasyMock.expect(mockClass.myMethod(
                        EasyMock.eq("exact string"), 
                        EasyMock.isA(Long.class), 
                        EasyMock.isA(CustomObject.class)));
```

This is not matching the method correctly probably because of the Long which is supposed to be null.

I cannot put `EasyMock.isNull()` since it will be a specific matching and generics and specifics can't go together. Any tips ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't understand why you couldn't use `isNull()`.

```
EasyMock.expect(mockClass.myMethod(
                    EasyMock.eq("exact string"), 
                    EasyMock.isNull(Long.class), 
                    EasyMock.isA(CustomObject.class)));
```

should be fine. Or

```
EasyMock.expect(mockClass.myMethod(
                    EasyMock.eq("exact string"), 
                    EasyMock.<Long>isNull(), 
                    EasyMock.isA(CustomObject.class)));
```

which should be fine as well.

What you can't have is

```
EasyMock.expect(mockClass.myMethod(
                    EasyMock.eq("exact string"), 
                    null, 
                    EasyMock.isA(CustomObject.class)));
```